# DistanceFromPoints with multiple XY coordinates

Tags: r, spatial, raster

I'm trying to use distanceFromPoints function in `raster` package as:

```
distanceFromPoints(object,xy,...)
```

Where, object is raster and `xy` is matrix of `x` and `y` coordinates

Now, if my raster has, for example, 1000 cells and `xy` represents one point, I get 1000 values representing distances between `xy` and each raster cell. my problem is when `xy` has multiple coordinates, e.g., 10 points. the function description indicates that `xy` can be multiple points but when I run this function with multiple `XY` points, I still get only 1000 values while I'm expecting 1000 values for each coordinate in `XY`. How does this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

using `distanceFromPoints` on multiple points gives a single value for each raster cell, which is the distance to the nearest point to that cell.

To create raster layers giving the distance to each point separately, you can use `apply`

a reproducible example:

```
r = raster(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 10))
p = data.frame(x=runif(5), y=runif(5))
dp = apply(p, 1, function(p) distanceFromPoints(r,p))
```

This gives a list of raster layers, each having the distance to one point

```
# for example, 1st raster in the list has the distance to the 1st point
plot(dp[[1]])
points(p[1,])
```

[image]

For convenience, you can convert this list into a raster stack

```
st = stack(dp)
plot(st)
```

[image]

**A final word of caution:**

It should be noted that the raster objects thus created do not really contain any more information than the list of points from which they are generated. As such, they are a computationally- and memory-expensive way to store that information. I can't easily think of any situation in which this would be a sensible way to solve a specific question. Therefore, it may be worth thinking again about the reasons you want these raster layers, and asking whether there may be a more efficient way to solve you overall problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying not to use apply or any loop because there are thousands of points that I'm dealing with and this turns into a time consuming calculation in my code. But as you pointed out, this seems to be the only option. Thank you so much for the response.

Comment: Glad it helped. If this was useful and answered your question, please consider upvoting by clicking on the up arrow, and accepting answer by clicking on the tick (check) mark. This is the preferenced way to say thanks in SO, rather than in comments.